# Best way to remember selected page in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a pagination with 10 pages of vehicles in list-vehicles.component. When user click on 5th page and open some vehicle there it navigates to vehicle.component, and when click back, I want user to stay on page 5. What is the best way to implement that?

In my list-vehicles.component I initilize `page = 1;` And everytime list-vehicles.component is loaded, it get back to first page.

And what if I have pagination in multiple components (for example vehicles,users,backgrounds...), do I need to handle all of them separately ?

Comment: You can cache the data on the frontend using BehaviourSubjects or store them in localStorage. Also save the pagination details before routing to other component.

Comment: Have you tried to use a modal to display the component vehicle ?

Comment: No I haven't. Because in vehicle component I use modal to display images and other things and I think it would be to much.

Comment: Another option is store in a service the page before you see the detail. Remember that a service can be a simple service with a public variable "page" and that the service is maintain to the live of the application -and you has not to store in localStore the variable -really if you don't need that the next time your visitor remember the page it's not necesary-

Comment: Store it in the URL as a query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As @AhmerMH says, you can save it to `localStorage`. On each change of the page, you update the value in the `localStorage` and instead of `page = 1` you'll have `page = localStorage.getItem(<KEY_NAME>)`.

I suppose in you call to BE for data you have some param like `offset` or something similar. You just add the page number stored in the `localStorage` there.

Comment: Is the best practice to save to LocalStorage every different paginations I have? Then I would have vehiclePage, userPage in LocalStorage and so on ?

Comment: I think it's ok. Another question is how you handle it. Maybe if you have many paginations, it would be better to create some service for it, so you don't have duplicate code in each component. You'll just pass the key and the value to the service.

Comment: Yes, for sure. I will do that. Thanks

Comment: @Stefan if you don't need that the user the next time see your page remember the pages it's better use a simple service

Comment: @Eliseo yeah, but if the user reloads the page, he'll be back to the first page. Maybe it makes sense to reset all pages except the current one on page reload.

Answer (score 0):

Complementary my comment. If you has a service like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StateService {
  vehiclePage:number;
  userPage:number;
  
  constructor() { }

}
```

your component like

```
page=this.stateService.vehiclePage?this.stateService.vehiclePage:1
constructor(private stateService:StateService,private router:Router){}

navigate(id)
{
    this.stateService.page=this.page;
    this.router.navigate(['vehicle/'+id]
}
```